# Liquibase 2.0.5 changesets failing for unknown reason

Tags: liquibase

I am working on a project with a lot of old code. Sadly the technologies used haven't been updated fom ages. So some time ago me and my co worker we got new laptops and after we set up our project around 40 changests failed when deploying the project. Most of these changesets are not even written by us and they have been in the system for more than 3 years and have not been altered by us in any way. Also they appear to be pretty random here are some examples:

```
classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-1::init is now: 3:1deaf0a4f097b6b849022f38c537ce2d
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-7::init is now: 3:20e80f95d9d5570a72baef55706ad0d4
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-11::init is now: 3:075b7b18949816c1dd771434814d1462
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-13::init is now: 3:65b98274ee2ee237eecac81f2c592bd8
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-15::init is now: 3:85ff7630667ee7fc38701701b16f0345
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-17::init is now: 3:6942fa10b9f19926c6cd0eae32e3e556
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-19::init is now: 3:c3787592a6482613500a708d34c5c8ac
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-20::init is now: 3:5867b027de501c8583a8943ef3d526d9
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-22::init is now: 3:90a88831937e9e92fad8f3d04e90d71b
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-24::init is now: 3:accaeaaec8b4fe66f3c92f90cca9a88c
      classpath:database/_dbchangelog.xml::pm-26::init is now: 3:df6a8efd77c403ccc9988554f830ba57
```

We were previously using locally Postgresql 9.3.9 but now I am with version 9.5.5. But the version is not the problem cause I have other co workers with version 9.5.5 and for them the changests are not failing. This is exactly the problem cause now if I update the system the changesets fail and if they update after that they have to fix them again and so on and so on. We are using the same branch the same Postgesql version and our liquibase is 2.0.5. Please if anyone have any idea why these changesets are failing any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The failure is because Liquibase thinks the changeset hashsum is different to the changeset hashsum that was applied to the database. Basically it thinks you have changed the changeset. If you say that they haven't changed, have your and your colleague changed the encoding of the files on your local machine? That would have an impact on the hashsum

Comment: The file is with explicitly specified UTF-8 encoding
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. And no we have not even touched this file.

Comment: Do the changesets run against a clean database?

Comment: No they do not. The database is working because we several clients using this project with different databases. Imagine if we have to make a live update each time I update i will have to fix these and if someone else update after he will have to change them again.

Comment: Sorry I meant that if you create a new database and run the changesets against a new database, do they apply cleanly?

Comment: Ah I see but due to the way the project was made it is impossible at the moment to have a clean database. The project will simply not run if we need a new database we copy tan existing one and just change some data in it but it cannot be clean :(

Comment: Is it possible to be from the WIndows 10 different build version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132986/discussion-between-rob-blake-and-krasimir-dimitrov).